# How to auto init direnv on Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, bashrc, google-cloud-shell

my .bashrc has these lines at the bottom:

```
if [ -f $HOME/tools/bashrc ]; then
        source $HOME/tools/bashrc
fi
```

and `$HOME/tools/bashrc` has this code at the bottom:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
pyenv virtualenvwrapper_lazy
eval "$(direnv hook bash)"
export DIRENV_LOG_FORMAT=
```

but when I access directories that contain `.envrc`, it's not reading it. I even tried to add `echo` just above the `eval "$(direnv hook bash)"` and it's echoing the text ok upon login or opening a new bash.

One interesting thing is this: When I access a directory that has `.envrc` in it, then run `tmux new -s <name>`, it will open a new bash and read the `.envrc`. But when I access another directory that has `.envrc` on that same tmux session, still does read it.

The only way for me to make it work is by manually typing `eval "$(direnv hook bash)"` upon login, which not ideal.

I even tried hardcoding everything at the bottom of `~/.bashrc` but still the same behavior. Is anyone has an idea? Thanks!